# Can't download Binance futures klines with 1s interval

Tags: python, binance, python-binance

I'm trying to download Binance USD-M futures 1s klines using Binance API

```
from binance.client import Client, HistoricalKlinesType

symbol = 'ETHUSDT'
interval = "1s"
date_from = "19 Aug 2023"
date_to = "20 Aug 2023"
client = Client()

klines = client.get_historical_klines(symbol, interval, date_from, date_to, klines_type=HistoricalKlinesType.FUTURES)
```

But receive error:

> binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1120): Invalid interval.

This problem presented only when trying to download futures klines, when spot used this code works. Maybe anyone know how to download this klines properly.

Comment: It clearly says the interval value is invalid. You need to check the API docs. Maybe `get_historical_klines` does not except `1s` as interval?

Answer (score 0):

`1s` is not an available interval for USD-M futures. The smallest one is the `1m`.